# Steam-related Python program

Tags: python, steam

I am working on making a program in Python that takes a list of dictionary words that the user enters (split up by commas or on separate lines) and then adds each one to the end of a URL (http://steamcommunity.com/id/) it then checks each one of the URLs and only prints the ones with "The specified profile could not be found." text on the web page (example http://prntscr.com/gjdzuf).

I understand this is most likely not very difficult, but I have only recently started learning Python, and I am just looking for the easiest method to do what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `requests` module. For something as simple as just checking whether the text is in the page, this would do:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://steamcommunity.com/id/')

if 'The specified profile could not be found.' in r.text:
    print('Invalid profile!')
else:
    print('Found a profile.')
```

For more complex processing, a parsing library such as `BeautifulSoup4` is needed.

This practice is referred to as "web scraping", and Python has great tools for it.